# Is it fine to change th order of authors in Arxiv?

Tags: authorship, arxiv, author-order

We have a paper on arxiv. For some reasons, we need to change the order of the authors. The first can be second. Is it fine ? or should we delete the paper on Arxiv and post it again with new names and authors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying an arXiv preprint is done with the "Replace" feature, and this allows you to make arbitrary changes to the Author metadata field.

There is no need to delete the paper, and trying to do so would likely cause more problems.  (You cannot actually delete an arXiv paper, you can only "withdraw" it, and trying to upload a preprint which is substantially identical to a withdrawn paper may be rejected due to excessive overlap.)

Just make sure that you also change the author order in the paper itself and upload new tex/pdf files, otherwise people will be confused.  And, of course, all of the authors must have consented to the new ordering.

Comment: if the file changes, what would happen to the first version ? it would still exit? if the paper has cited other papers, is this change would affect that citations.

Comment: @Heba Mohsen: *if the paper has cited other papers, is this change would affect that citations* --- Do you mean "YOUR paper has cited other papers" (I don't understand the concern) or do you mean "OTHER papers have cited your paper" (this is up to the other papers, and probably moot once the other papers have been published). By the way, the second interpretation is what I think you intended, but FYI by writing "the paper", you are actually saying the first interpretation (because there is only one paper you have previously mentioned that "the" could refer to).

Comment: @HebaMohsen: People who look at the arXiv page for the preprint will see the version history (v1, v2, etc) and have the option to view and download past versions. Past versions on arXiv can never be permanently deleted.  If other papers have already cited your preprint with the original author ordering, this will not do anything to change that; how could it?